# ACF file download not working, added screenshots

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I am trying to use ACF to add files to be able to download. And I am using the following code:

```
<?php if( get_field('jesmond_breakfast') ):?>
  <a href="<?php the_field('jesmond_breakfast'); ?>" target="_blank"><strong>Brochure</strong></a>
<?php
endif;?>
```

Then I have this set up in ACF.

[image]
[image]

But for some reason, I am having no luck.

Can anyone see the issue?

Comment: What exactly happens when you click on the link? Also, can you do a `var_dump()` for your field just after the `if` statement, and then paste the result here?

Answer (score 0):

```
 <?php if( get_field('jesmond_breakfast') ):?>
  <a href="<?php the_field('jesmond_breakfast'); ?>" target="_blank"><strong>Brochure</strong></a>
<?php
endif;?>
```

instead of you can store in variable after given in

```
<?php if( get_field('jesmond_breakfast') ): 
$link= the_field('jesmond_breakfast');?>
          <a href="<?php echo $link;  ?>" target="_blank"><strong>Brochure</strong></a>
        <?php
        endif;?>
```